# How to load more videos in recyclerview like images?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my program there are both images and videos loading in the recyclerview. I want to make a system so that the recyclerview can store more feeds so that when we scroll back we do not have to wait for the recyclerview to load data again.

In my code, I have successfully managed to store more image data. I have used the code:

```
mBlogList.setItemViewCacheSize(20);

mBlogList.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

//mBlogList is the name of the recyclerview.`
```

Now I want some code so that I can implement the same for video. In the current scenario, I have the images stored in recyclerview cache. But the videos aren't. Is there any code to do that for video?

Comment: I wouldn't advised you to save large cache in `RecyclerView`, you should use some cache  outside view. I.e. in your adapter but much better to use a something as [LruCache](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache).